# implementing of a linked list (data structure) and the return value is ignored

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

code includes the implementation of `addingToTail` in a linked list (data structure in javaScript).
I was hoping if someone could answer why the existence of return in the following code makes no significant difference. as `return` part is optional.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this._size = 0;
  }

  addToTail(value) {
   if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = addnode;
      this.tail = addnode;
      this._size++;
      return;
    }
    else {
      this.tail.next = addnode;
      this.tail = addnode;
      this._size++;
      return;
  }
```

Comment: What difference would you expect the `return;` to make?

Comment: `addnode` is not declared or initialised anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from function at the end of both possible conditions.

> Code #1 (Your code, added missing semi-colon)

```
addToTail(value) {
   if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = addnode;
      this.tail = addnode;
      this._size++;
      return;
    }
    else {
      this.tail.next = addnode;
      this.tail = addnode;
      this._size++;
      return;
    }
}
```

> Code #2

```
addToTail(value) {
    if (this.head === null) {
        this.head = addnode;
        this.tail = addnode;
        this._size++;
    }
    else {
        this.tail.next = addnode;
        this.tail = addnode;
        this._size++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Both code #1 & #2 are same as return are at the end.

> ## EDIT 1: Update function to use tail member.
>
> Ideally this function would something like:

```
addToTail(value) {
    const newNode = new Node(value);
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
    this._size++;
    return newNode;
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Also look at this LinkedList class I have created, `_InsertRawTypeItem` function is matching the requirement you have.
[Class GitHub](https://github.com/dsinjs/linked-list)
[NPM package - @dsinjs/linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/linked-list)
[Complete documentation](https://dsinjs.github.io/linked-list/#traverse)

Comment: "*Ideally this function would something like*" - no, it should not have to do any looping.

Comment: Aaah I see, he has tail member in his class, he would just assign new Node to tail's next and make this new Node a tail node. Usually linked list does not have a tail Node right? So I missed it.

Comment: Most of them have, because it's such a cheap, simple and effective optimisation.

Comment: @Bergi That is true